# How load data from database if specific thymeleaf segment included in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I use Spring and Thymeleaf. there is a thymeleaf segment used for sidebar menu that is included in some pages.

My question:

Is there any way to register that if the segment included in main theme then load related data from database and add it to model? (I used something like this in php Laravel 5)

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the full context.
can you please give any example or give a detail explanation.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to check that some UI component is loaded then only you load data from the database, right?

Comment: Did you look into [LazyContextVariable][1]? 
 http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.0.BETA03/org/thymeleaf/context/LazyContextVariable.html . See github thread https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/101

Comment: I guess you are here mixing pull and push style mvc. which in long run would become unmanageable spagetti. While you are on a spring side, I would recommend you to push all your necessary data from controller, thus your controller is selecting which UI is needed, and which data controller should push.  If you would like to pull data to your presentation then go to JSF world.

Comment: @mohsenkw maybe this helps: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html#spring-beans. it allows you to call a method of any spring bean using the spring el inside your fragment

Comment: @TommySchmidt That's a good point

Answer (score 0):

Get the data from DB and add it in a model from controller's methods. Then on the front end, just check that if that value is null or not. If that value is not null, show this fragment. For example: you set a value in controller like this:

```
model.addAttribute("errors",this.DAOLayer.getItemsToShowOnAParticularFragment());
```

then on the front end side:

```
<c:if test="${errors != null}"> 
<div class="alert>
<table class="table">                                   
<c:forEach items="${errors}" var="error">
<tr><td><c:out value="${error.defaultMessage}" /></td></tr>
</c:forEach>                                                        
</table>
</div>
</c:if>
```

I do that on my JSPs. When errors are null, the whole `<div>` doesn't show up. That `<div>` only shows up when errors is not null.

You can set another if statement that if errors are null, show this instead.

```
<c:if test="${errors == null}">
<!-- Since nothing came from DB, show this info in this fragment -->
```

**Further explanation:**

Say you have set aside a part of your front-end that shows these messages from database. I will use bootstrap as an example. Say that the circled `<div>` is the area you have assigned for it.

[image]

The front-end code to produce such layout is this (it includes all the import statements to import Bootstrap libraries):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Start of circled div  -->
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 3</h3>        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <!-- End of circled columns -->
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now **inside** this last `<div class="col-sm-4"> ....`, you will put that `<c:if test="${errors != null}">` JSTL code to test what content to show to the user. I hope you know how to use and import JSTL tags in your front-end. If not then you can google it and you will find plenty of answers. 
And that is it.